# Devtools Document throwing Error

Tags: r, devtools

I am putting together an R data package, and I have been documenting the datasets without issue until now.  The following is included in a file called `charges_ay.R` located in the `R` folder in package repo.

```
#' Student Charges for Academic Year programs.
#'
#' For more information, download a data dictionary from the IPEDS website.
#' 
#' Survey years 2002 - 2014.
#'
#' @source http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/DataFiles.aspx
#' @format Data frame with columns
"charges_ay"
```

When I attempt to run `devtools::document` from the base of the package (as I have for the other files), I get the following error:

```
> devtools::document()
Updating ripeds documentation
Loading ripeds
Error: 'charges_ay' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ripeds'
```

Given that everything has worked fine until now, I am bit confused as the process and file documentation are all the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be safe, try adding `@name` and `@usage` fields to the documentation. It _may_ be the source of the problem, but in any case, it would only help.

Comment: does the data exist? Do you have `LazyData: TRUE` in the DESCRIPTION file? I think these get added automatically if you use `devtools::use_data()`

Comment: @Jemus42 that is bad advice

Comment: @Jemus42 Thanks, I added those but no dice. I did, however, conclude with NULL and that seemed to have worked, but not sure what was different in this file as compared to the others.

Comment: @rmflight I do have LazyData: True, thanks though

Comment: what does your directory structure look like? in particular, what is the result of `ls data` run in your package root? (Oops: missed your comment of Mar 24). So you put `NULL` as the final line of `changes_ay.R` and that worked?

Answer (score 4):

When I ran in to this in my own package, it seemed to be a workflow issue.  Try either running `use_data(charges_ay)` prior to `document()`, or adding `use_data(charges_ay)` at the end of your data-generating file.